# Java translator

Tags: java, xml

I need to create a web service for translating between two languages in my choice. On this web service, DB data of words is necessary to be located in one XML file, arbitrary structures. When the client demands a particular word for translate, web service checks does this word exists in DB. If the word exists web service like output show this translated word to the client. If not show an error message.Calling this method can look like this translate("butterfly", "english", "russian");

I think it's a simple task but I can not find any tutorial about this. Can anybody help me to find a tutorial about this or tell me how to solve this problem? Also, this task must be written in java language.

Thanks.

Comment: first of all, no java tag. You probably don't want it (unless it's a java program what you want to do, but I think it's not)

Comment: You should break this down into more specific questions. We do not know what you know and what not about web services, databases, Java and software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the first thing you want to decide is which technology you want to choose. If you want to use Java I would recommend building a rest service with spring. Takes about 5 minutes with those two guides: 
Rest Web Service: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/
Rest Client: https:[//spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/](http:////spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/)

IDE: Springt Tool Suite

Just follow the instruction! Your task will be part of the service method i.e. "translate".